# How to use Android 'flavor' strings.xml

Tags: android, gradle

I have an app which will have free and paid versions.  I can successfully created 'flavors' in the build.gradle and created new folders under 'src'.

I have added a strings.xml to each flavor.

src/flavor1/res/values/strings.xml

src/flavor2/res/values/strings.xml

It is one bool:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="FullVersion">false</bool>
</resources>
```

One flavor is true, one is false.  I don't have this same 'bool' in my 'strings.xml' under the main folder.

I am trying to reference this in a layout in the main folder to determine if something is enabled or disabled.

[image]

Looks like this is what has been confusing me.  You're right.  It does work however, my enabled shows an error and the preview won't render because of it.
It does work though

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:enabled="@bool/FullVersion"`.

That being said, you might wish to move this resource to a `bools.xml` file, or at least out of `strings.xml`, to simplify your translation work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  That doesn't work.  I can't see the 'FullVersion' in the strings.xml in the flavors.

Comment: @B-Rad: I do not know what "I can't see..." means in this context. I just added `flavor1` and `flavor2` to a scrap project, with `bools.xml` files for each with your `bool` resource. I have no problem having Android Studio recognize `android:enabled="@bool/FullVersion"` in a layout resource.

Comment: Is it in a layout resource that is NOT contained within one of the flavors?

Comment: @B-Rad: Yes, the layout resource was in the `main` sourceset. I just added it to one of the existing layout resources that Android Studio generated when I created the project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem here.  I needed to define more information in my 'flavors':

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 1
```

Everything works now.